I have a memory leak in a C function using NumPy C-API and i have no idea why
I tried to write a convolution function in C for 3d numpy arrays, the result i get is right but when i use the function in a big loop (let's say for example with a couple of millions of iterations) the memory usage keeps growing until i kill the process. The documentation says that PyArray_Free should be called to free the memory used by PyArray_AsCArray and i did it, however i still have the memory leak and i don't know why (i didn't use the function with result because that would give me a segfault)
PyObject* conv3d(PyObject* self, PyObject* args){
 
    PyObject* arr3d;
    PyObject* kernel3d;

    if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "OO", &arr3d, &kernel3d)) {
        return NULL;
    }
 
    // dummy dimensions values only for example
    Py_ssize_t dimarr[3] = {0};
    Py_ssize_t dimkernel[3] = {0};
    npy_intp output_shape[] = {2,2};
 
    int typenum = NPY_FLOAT;
    PyObject* result = PyArray_SimpleNew(2, output_shape, typenum);
    PyArray_FILLWBYTE((PyArrayObject*) result, 0);
 
    double*** data_arr3d;
    double*** data_kernel3d;
    double** data_result;
 
    PyArray_AsCArray((PyObject**)&arr3d, &data_arr3d, dimarr,3, PyArray_DescrFromType(NPY_DOUBLE));
    PyArray_AsCArray((PyObject**)&kernel3d, &data_kernel3d, dimkernel,3, PyArray_DescrFromType(NPY_DOUBLE));
    PyArray_AsCArray((PyObject**)&result, &data_result, output_shape,2, PyArray_DescrFromType(NPY_DOUBLE));

    /* code to compute the result */
 
    PyArray_Free((PyObject*)arr3d, data_arr3d); 
    PyArray_Free((PyObject*)kernel3d, data_kernel3d);
    //PyArray_Free((PyObject*)result, data_result); // segfault
 
    return result;
}

I tried to see what happens to the refcount of the arrays and i noticed a weird behaviour, sometimes the call to PyArray_AsCArray increments the count (printing Py_REFCNT(arr3d) before and after the call would show 3 and 4) but in some other cases it decrements it two times showing 3 before and 1 after the call. I didn't know if that was normal so i also tried to handle refcounts manually with Py_INCREF(arr3d) and Py_DECREF(arr3d) to force them to be the same as in the start of the function but that didn't work neither.

Please read [ask]. We do not write answers here that "find the bug"; we require a specific question - which will come out of your best attempt to understand and locate a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre]. A question that is suitable for Stack Overflow is one where you have already figured out the specific part of the code that does something different from what you expect (and you should concretely expect something), and don't understand why.

Which is to say: identifying that this function has a memory leak is the first step. The next step is to remove functionality and see if the memory leak still occurs, until you figure out the part of the code that is actually responsible.

Did you tried to run valgrind on this? I might be able to locate the leak.

@KarlKnechtel thank you for the answer, i did what you said and i found out that the cause of the leak seems to be the call to PyArray_AsCArray for the result array that was previously allocated, using PyArray_SimpleNew. This makes sense because before returning the result i call PyArray_Free only for the two input arrays but if i try to call it also for result i get segmentation fault

As explained in the documentation, you should only use the explicit free functions for memory you explicitly allocate. For objects you create in the code using the API, you need to use the API to maintain the reference count, so that the garbage collector can work properly.
